# IntelliJ IDEA: Increase size of bar on the right side of editor

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, editor, customization, intellij-14

I'd like to increase the size of the bar on the right side of the Editor in IntelliJ IDEA. It's simply way too small for my taste.

It is the bar where the warnings or usages are displayed.

P. S.: The bar is called *Error Stripe*.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#d1187816e280) help you?

Comment: @UmutSeven Unfortunately not. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it – or the scrollbar as a whole – can't be resized.

Answer (score 27):

I agree, the scrollbar is far to small, and hard to see.

Another option you could try is installing the "CodeGlance" plugin which adds a full view of the code and makes scrolling far more intuituve.

[image: Screen shot of IntelliJ with CodeGlance]
Grab it from (as of 15-04-27) https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7275?pr=clion

Comment: Cool... But now i am curious... How did you show the "tab" symbols? And what color scheme is this?

Comment: That is CodeGlance's screenshot, not mine. However, I believe the colour scheme (theme) is "Dracula" , and don't the tab symbols always show? They do on my IntelliJ with version 14.

Comment: Is there no native way of showing such a bar? The ReSharper (which is developed by Intellij) brings exactly the same bar to VisualStudio.

Comment: OK, that will work for the vertical scroll bar.  I'l llearn to live with the horizontal one.  @Mateus Viccari, the symbols show on my tabs by default.

Comment: @MateusViccari see **Settings** > **Editor** > **General** > **Appearance** > `Show whitespaces`.   Or set it for current file only in **View**  > **Active Editor** > **Show WhiteSpaces**

Answer (score 17):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and select `Registry...` from the menu that appears.

Look for **`editor.full.width.scrollbar`** and tick the box on the right. The change should take effect after clicking the close button. The width of the scroll bar should be marginally wider, it's not a lot but every little bit helps :-)

Unfortunately this setting only affects the scroll bar on the right of the editor window. All the other scroll bars are unaffected.

For those that find transparency effects annoying then look for **`editor.transparent.scrollbar`** and untick the box on the right. This change should take effect after clicking the close button and restarting IntelliJ.

Comment: It's today that I learned about the "Registry..." thing. This is a complete life changer! Also if the the editor-related  settings do not not apply immediately after closing the registry window, try to yank the editor width back and forth (e.g. by resizing the side panel). I guess it just needs a force redraw. Alright, I'm going back to the Registry... see ya

Answer (score -1):

You could scroll to the bottom of the bars properties in the GUI section  and change the width to example (100dp). Or you could play around with the XML file that contains the width and height property.

Comment: Where can I find this in the settings?

Comment: @HaroldL.Brown in the GUI scroll down in the properties and then change the width. Or open your layout XML and change the width and height property.

Comment: Could you maybe post a screenshot? I still can't figure out where to look from your answer.